# dotCloud nginx.conf: how to get the "index index.php" directive to work?

Tags: dotcloud

I got auth to work by "pushing" an nginx.conf file in the application directory, so I know the file works, but /app will not trigger /app/php.index.    I can't get nginx working on my vista laptop with php and I can't edit the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf in the dotCloud instance as dotCloud makes life difficult by not giving root.

(Note that the .htpasswd is relative to the ngnix.conf file location, nice).

```
server { 

location / {
          index  index.php;
}


location /admin {
            auth_basic "enter password";
            auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    index  index.php;
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need an nginx directive to map requests to your dynamic content. This controller can can then route them appropriately.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

For an example project, see the [CakePHP tutorial](http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/tutorials/php/cakephp/).